# Java: How does use of Optional.empty() compile?

Tags: java, java-8

This seems like a really stupid question, but I can't understand *why* this use of `Optional<T>` compiles:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Driver {
    static void foo(Optional<String> x) { }

    public static void main() {
        foo(Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

[`Optional::empty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) is defined as returning me an `Optional<T>`. Inside of `Driver::main`, the expression `Optional.empty()` seems like it would return an `Optional<Object>`, as I am not parameterizing the use of `Optional` so I would expect it to fall back to `Object` as the type parameter. Then, I'm passing the `Optional<Object>` to a function which expects an `Optional<String>`, which is a downcast of the parameter, which should not be allowed. I would expect to see something like:

```
incompatible types: Optional<Object> cannot be converted to Optional<String>
```

However, the code compiles perfectly fine. Clearly, my thought process here is incorrect...but where?

---

Let me clarify what I'm looking for in an answer here...I know what type inference is. What I don't understand *how* it is happening here and what changed in the language from Java 7 to Java 8. For example, this bit of code compiles perfectly fine in Java 8, but fails in Java 7:

```
final class Opt<T> {
    private final T value;

    Opt(T x) {
        value = x;
    }

    public static <T> Opt<T> empty() {
        return new Opt<T>(null);
    }
}

public class Driver {
    static void bar(Opt<String> x) { }

    public static void main() {
        bar(Opt.empty());
    }
}
```

How does this work in Java 8 when you have to deal with things like overloading? Is there a specific section of the Java language specification that talks about this sort of thing?

Comment: type inference is a cool thing

Comment: That doesn't answer the question usefully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of the way way the empty() method is defined in Optional:

```
public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Optional<T> t = (Optional<T>) EMPTY;
    return t;
}
```

Note the method type parameter above:

```
public static<T> Optional<T> empty() {
             ^^^ method type parameter
```

This means that when empty() is called, it will bind T to the context of its caller, in your case String.  For more information, see the section on Target Types in this page in the Java Tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: +1 on type parameter. Not so sure about the inference part though. I mean, a type parameter declaration is pretty explicit.

Answer (score 9):

Since that part of your question has not been addressed, I will try to summarize what have changed between Java 7 and Java 8.

Java 7 already had *type inference*, e.g. you could write

```
List<String> list=Collections.emptyList();
```

or

```
List<String> getList() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

But this type inference was rather limited, e.g. what did not work (besides others) was:

```
List<String> list=Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.emptyList());
```

or

```
List<String> getList() {
    return condition? new ArrayList<>(): Collections.emptyList();
}
```

These two examples work now under Java 8. This new feature is called *target type inference* as it now uses the target’s type to find the appropriate type arguments. Besides making nested method invocations and conditionals work, like in the examples above, it also fixes the following example:

```
List<Number> numbers=Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

As said, Java 7 had *type inference* too, but in this example it would infer `List<Integer>` as the result type of the expression from the arguments passed to `asList` and hence, generate an error.

In contrast, Java 8 has *target type inference* and will use the target type of the assignment to infer `List<Number>` as the type of the expression and find out that the entire statement is valid as you can use `Integer` objects where `Number` is expected.

Note that `Optional.empty()` and `Collections.emptyList()` use the same kind of Generic construct. I used the latter in my examples as it already exists in Java 7.

Answer (score 5):

It because the compiler does type inference.

When the compiler read:

```
static void foo(Optional<String> x) { }

public static void main() {
    foo(Optional.empty());
}
```

- It knows that `Optional.<T>empty()` take a `T` as a parameter.
- It knows that `foo` expect an `Optional<String>`
- It infers that `T` is `String`.

It was introduced when generics where introduced, and perhaps the mechanism of it was improved with Java 8's `javac`.

Note that this depends on the compiler: ECJ (Eclipse JDT Compiler) does not understands the same java source that Javac understands (they do, however, compile the "same" bytecode).

Answer (score -1):

Java 8 added type interface which means it will work out the type of an expression based on how it is used.

A blatent example is

```
Object o = () -> System.out.println("Hello World");
```

doesn't compile because it doesn't know the type of the expression however,

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello World"); 

Object o = (Runnable) () -> System.out.println("Hello World");
```

compile fine.  ie the type of the expression changes due the way it is used.